# In what situations unit testing should be avoided?

Tags: unit-testing

When is unit testing harmful?  it can't be used in all situations and it should be selective, do you know situations when it should be avoided?

Comment: Unit-testing is never, ever, harmful

Comment: This question is more suitable for Stack Excange and already has an answer there: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/147055/when-is-unit-testing-inappropriate-or-unnecessary

Comment: Why is it down-voted? It is never wrong to ask why effort should be put into something.

Answer (score 1):

Unit tests should always be simpler than the productive logic which is tested. So if you have trivial logic which can only be tests with a lot of staging, I would avoid unit tests.

Unit tests can become a nightmare when they become a maintenance problem. Unless you are willing to just remove them as soon as it starts creating a lot of work. Clean unit test usually are less prone to maintenance problems. This is actually not an argument against unit tests, it is an argument for isolated, simple unit tests.